# UT2003 Installation Problems (The setup program seems to have failed on x86/unknown)

Tags: 14.04, games

I'm trying to install Unreal Tournament 2003 on my Ubuntu 14.04 (I have the CDs as ISO files) and, I've followed some different instructions on how to do it, but ran into this kind of problem:

```
linux32 sh ./linux_installer.sh

Copying to a temporary location...
Verifying archive integrity...An embedded MD5 sum of the archive exists but no md5sum program was found in /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:   /bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
If you have md5sum on your system, you should try :
env GUESS_MD5_PATH="FirstDirectory:SecondDirectory:..." /tmp/makeself5187 -check
All good.
Uncompressing Unreal Tournament 2003 for GNU/Linux 2199....................................................................
.setup5210: dynamic-link.h:57: elf_get_dynamic_info: Assertion `! "bad dynamic tag"' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
The setup program seems to have failed on x86/unknown

Fatal error, no tech support email configured in this setup
The program returned an error code (1)
```

There seems to have been same kinds of problems before, but haven't found answers yet how to fix this :/

Comment: *bumppadi-dums*

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to install ut2003 on an ubuntu 14.10, I described the steps [here](https://github.com/jdupouy/ut2003/blob/master/README.md).

I can't run the linux_installer due to the same error (it seems that we should use an old version of glibc (2.1) which is not available maybe by trying to compile it from sources). The linux_installer.sh is a self-extracting archive containing the ut2003-bin launcher and the ucc.

The workaround I found was to use the ut2003_2225beta3-multilanguage.update.run patch that you can find [here](http://liandri.beyondunreal.com/Unreal_Tournament_2003#Essential_Files) and which contains those files. (The link also provides bonus pack, community pack, etc...)

By following the steps described in the link above the installation works fine.

***The following is just for information***

**Note 1:** The following command will extract the content of the archive (works for other patch and bonus pack as well).

```
linux32 sh ut2003_2225beta3-multilanguage.update.run --target ut2003_2225beta3
```

This will create a directory named `ut2003_2225beta3` containing a `data` directory which as the same structure as the ut2003 installation directory, you can then just copy all the files to your installation.

The others packs or bonus work the same, sometimes the update is compressed, you have to decompress it, but in fine you will find a standard ut2003 folder structure that you just have to copy to your install.

**Unfortunately** this does not work for the linux_installer.sh, by the way the command must be modified as follow

```
_POSIX2_VERSION=199209 linux32 sh linux_installer.sh --target linux_installer
```

**I'm still looking for a solution to extract the content of a self-extracting archive without running it.**

**Note 2:** You can even use the .exe packs installation executables, just unzip the exe files (`unzip nameofthepack.exe -d nameofthepack`) and you will recognize the ut2003 structure. (This does not work for patch 2225b3 as it must contains the linux executable ut2003-bin and ucc which the exe does not contain obviously)

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Julien

Comment: Those .sh self-extractors are generally makeself archives and, sure enough, `This script was generated using Makeself 2.0.1`. That means you just open it up in a text editor and figure out on what line the tarball's data starts. In this case, you can replicate what it does without running it by running `tail -n +266 linux_installer.sh | tar xvf -` (Skip to line 266, then feed the contents to `tar` for extraction)